# Import code from LaTeXDraw to writeLaTeX

Tags: diagrams, technical-drawing, import, overleaf

I am new to LaTeX. I am trying to write my master thesis using `WriteLaTeX`. I wanted to make some figures using `LaTeXDraw`. However, I want to import the code to my report and not the final picture. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have to give us more information. What problem are you having. LaTeXDraw has a function to export PSTricks instead of the final picture. You may insert that code in your document, not matter if that is on WriteLatex or some other editor. If your code does not work inside your document, show us as short as possible, what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tutorial on the latexdraw website explaining how to include the generated code into a latex document:
http://latexdraw.sourceforge.net/start.html

Another solution is to export your drawing produced by latexdraw as a PDF or PS picture and to include it into your document.

Comment: Dead link now. Do you know the new location?

Comment: New location: https://github.com/arnobl/latexdraw/wiki/Manual